# Problem sending email with template_id with Airflow and Sendgrid

Tags: python, airflow, sendgrid, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to send an email with Sendgrid and [Airflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Airflow) (2.4.2). I am able to send the email, but when I try to pass a *template_id*, the email is sent without the template design. It looks like I am passing the template_id in the incorrect way. How can I send the email with the template?.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.postgres.hooks.postgres import PostgresHook
from airflow.providers.sendgrid.utils.emailer import send_email

from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator

from datetime import datetime


default_args = {
    'owner': 'your_name',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 16, 15, 35, 0),
    'retries': 1,
}

#Task to send an email using SendGrid
def _send_email():

    postgres_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="postgres")
    sql_query = "select email from Users where firstname='Raghav';"
    results = postgres_hook.get_records(sql_query)

    for row in results:
        email = row
        email_content = f"Hello  Email: {email}\n"

        send_email(
            to=email,
            subject='Test Email Subject',
            html_content=email_content,
            files=None,  # List of file paths to attach to the email
            cc=None,  # List of email addresses to CC
            bcc=None,  # List of email addresses to BCC
            conn_id='sendgrid_default',
            template_id='d-8cefbe24e73842d7810550fc441aceb0', #didn't work
            kwargs={
                'template_id':'d-8cefbe24e99942d7810550fc441aceb0'
            }
        )

with DAG('user_processing',
        start_date=datetime(2022,1,1),
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        catchup=False) as dag:

    email_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'email_user',
        python_callable= _send_email
    )

    email_user
```

Comment: By the way. I was trying using the import 'airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators.sendgrid_email'.  I installed it with 'pip install apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid', however, VSCode is showing me 'Import "airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators.sendgrid_email" could not be resolved' and the webconsole is showing me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators'" Should I use any specific version? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is using a PythonOperator, sending a request to v3 using personalization.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
import requests

headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {sendgrid_api_key}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

data = {
    "personalizations": [
        {
            "to": [
                {
                    "email": "recipient1@example.com",
                    "name": "Recipient 1 Name"
                },
                {
                    "email": "recipient2@example.com",
                    "name": "Recipient 2 Name"
                }
            ],
            "subject": "Your Email Subject"
        }
    ],
    "from": {
        "email": "sender@example.com",
        "name": "Sender Name"
    },
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "text/plain",
            "value": "Hello, this is the plain text content of the email."
        },
        {
            "type": "text/html",
            "value": "<p>Hello, this is the HTML content of the email.</p>"
        }
    ]
}


requests.post("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send", json=data, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score -2):

Twilio Dev Advocate here.

To send an email with a SendGrid template, you should use the SendGridEmailOperator instead of the `send_email` function from the `airflow.providers.sendgrid.utils.emailer` module. Here's how you can modify your code to send an email with a SendGrid template:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators.sendgrid_email import SendGridEmailOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'your_name',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 16, 15, 35, 0),
    'retries': 1,
}

# Task to send an email using SendGrid
def _send_email():
    # Your code to retrieve the recipient email address and any other necessary data

    sendgrid_email = SendGridEmailOperator(
        task_id='sendgrid_email_task',
        to='recipient@example.com',
        subject='Test Email Subject',
        html_content='Hello Email: recipient@example.com',
        conn_id='sendgrid_default',
        template_id='d-8cefbe24e73842d7810550fc441aceb0',  # Your template ID
    )
    sendgrid_email.execute(context=None)

with DAG('user_processing',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval='@daily',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args) as dag:

    email_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id='email_user',
        python_callable=_send_email
    )

    email_user
```

In the code above, we import the SendGridEmailOperator from the `airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators.sendgrid_email` module, which is specifically designed to work with SendGrid templates. Then, we use this operator to send the email with the template, specifying the template ID as you have done in your code.

Make sure to adjust the recipient's email address and any other data you need to include in the email content. This code should send an email using the specified SendGrid template.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Dear Shivhappens, I did that as well. I installed the package with 'pip install apache-airflow-providers-sendgrid', however, VSCode is showing me 'Import "airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators.sendgrid_email" could not be resolved' and the webconsole is showing me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.sendgrid.operators'" Should I use any specific version? Do you have an example?

Comment: Has this been generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).